# Columntype of a column in a view

Tags: teradata, rdbms

Is there any way to find the column type of the columns in a view. For example for tables we can fire 
`select Columntype from dbc.tables where tablename=:name and databasename=:name;`

But for views the above query always returns null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way to get detailed metadata for views columns:

```
help column databasename.tablename.*;
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there no other way to extract them from the dbc objects as in dbc.tables/columns. @dnoeth

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation: https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-Database-Administration/March-2019/Working-with-Tables-and-Views-Application-DBAs/Working-with-Views/Obtaining-Information-about-View-Columns

The DBC.ColumnsV[X] views provide complete information for table columns but provide only limited information for view columns. For view columns, DBC.ColumnsV[X] provides a NULL value for ColumnType, DecimalTotalDigits, DecimalFractionalDigits, CharType, ColumnLength, and other attributes related to data type.

To obtain complete information about view columns, issue a SELECT request on either DBC.ColumnsQV[X] or DBC.ColumnJQV[X]. A SELECT request on DBC.ColumnsQV[X] or DBC.ColumnsJQV[X] can also be joined with other views and tables.

DBC.ColumnsQV[X] provides the same information as DBC.ColumnsV[X] for all database objects. DBC.ColumnsQV[X] additionally provides complete information for view columns.
DBC.ColumnsJQV[X] provides the same information as DBC.ColumnsV[X] for tables, NoPI tables, and views, and DBC.ColumnsJQV[X] additionally provides complete information for view columns. DBC.ColumnsJQV[X] does not provide information for database objects other than tables, NoPI tables, and views. The filter improves performance for requests that return information about tables and views only.

Comment: Those Q-views are currently disabled, they were some issues when accessing them with very old client versions.